# Why is import-csv failing when cmd runs manually?

Tags: powershell, import-csv

So I have this very simple script that I am using invoke-command to execute a cmd line on a bunch of remote nodes. The csv has 2 columns, host & stub. The csv has no whitespaces or anything.

```
import-csv test.csv | foreach-object {
    $host = $_.host
    $stub = $_.stub

    icm -computername $host -scriptblock {cmd /c c:\path\to\executable.exe <executable switches>  $stub  }
}
```

where $stub is part of the input for the executable.

If I run this verbatim with values for $host & $stub from the PS prompt, it works, but if I import-csv it throws Winrm errors

What am I missing here?

Errors from script but not from running it manually from PS prompt

```
[system.management.automation.internal.host.internalhost] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error m
essage : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Kerberos authentication: The network
 path was not found.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or us
e HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information,
 see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
Cannot overwrite variable Host because it is read-only or constant.
At C:\temp\bulk_rereg.ps1:2 char:6
+ $host <<<<  = $_.host
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Host:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable
```

Comment: Please provide the full text of those `Winrm errors`, so other people with the same errors can find your question.

Comment: Is the CSV file "clean" for the hostnames.? Can you recreate the csv with just one row retyping the computername that is working? Make sure there isn't any extra whitespace characters or any other unnecessary characters with the computername. For instance if your computername cell is ending with a period "." it can throw a WinRM error although it's slightly different than the one you are getting.

Comment: yes.. thank you for asking but the csv file is good. No whitespaces no extra lines, nothing.

Comment: I think the issue is your variable named `$host`. It is a [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3) so you'll need to change `$host` to something else.

Comment: In short: Because a script block passed to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ...` executes _remotely_, it knows nothing about the caller's _local_ variables. The simplest way to reference the caller's variable values is with the `$using:` scope; alternatively, pass the variable values as positional arguments via `-ArgumentList`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Stub is a local variable.
It does not exist in the remote machine.

To use a remote variable ([Refrence Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.3))

Option 1: "use:"
You can reference a remote variable without specific delcaration by utilizing the "use:" method.

```
import-csv test.csv | foreach-object {
$host = $_.host
$stub = $_.stub

icm -computername $host -scriptblock {cmd /c c:\path\to\executable.exe <executable switches>  $using:stub  }
}
```

Option 2: ArgumentList parameter
Use the ArgumentList parameter and declaration of the passed variable

```
import-csv test.csv | foreach-object {
$host = $_.host
$stub = $_.stub

icm -computername $host -scriptblock {
param($stub2)
cmd /c c:\path\to\executable.exe <executable switches>  $stub2  } -ArgumentList $stub
}
```

This is acts like a function.
The Argument list arguments are the passed variable and the Param(variable) is how the variable name in the remote machine will be called

($stub is passing the value to $stub2)
The name can be the same for easier use.

Comment: thanks so much, but also, doesn't work in either scenario.

Comment: again, if enter the actual values, it works fine
`
`icm -computername server123 -scriptblock {cmd /c c:\path\to\executable.exe <executable switches>  stub-xyz  }
}`
`

Comment: *technically* $stub is also a switch for the executable. Not sure if that would matter. Just trying to understand why the import-csv & foreach does NOT work when typing the whole thing out with actual values does work.

Comment: thank you @elior  i was able to get it to work using Option 2

Comment: I am glad one of the options worked for you.